# document.getElementsByClassName returning undefined despite having that class in the HTML doc

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a javascript function that is called after a button is pressed.  I'm trying to get the id of the first (and only) element of a certain class.  It's returning undefined, but I know that it's there, as the styling on it works.  The `var currentId = document.getElementsByClassName('item1')[0].id;` returns an id, however `var whereKey = document.getElementsByClassName('key')[0].id;` returns undefined.

```js
function runOnButton() {
  var currentId = document.getElementsByClassName('item1')[0].id;
  var whereKey = document.getElementsByClassName('key')[0].id;
  console.log(whereKey);

  if (currentId == whereKey) {
    //do stuff
    return true;
  } else {
    //do stuff
    return false;
  }

}

runOnButton();
```

```html
<div id="12" class="key"></div>
<div id="13" class="item1"></div>
```

Comment: Works fine here

Comment: @Stacey thank you for reducing your code to the minimum to show the problem, but you seem to have reduced it to the point of removing the problem. It appears to work fine here.

Comment: I made whereKey a global variable and find it's id right after startup instead and that seemed to have fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably that you aren't waiting until the document loads. Insert this into your script tag:

```js
window.onload = function() {
   //Insert your code here
}
```

OR make your script a module so it gets deferred

```html
<script type='module'>
    //Insert code here
</script>
```